# preg_match for verify string codes

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to verify this codes in php with preg_match but i dont manage regular expressions:

`R{1 TO 12}-{00 TO 99}-{00 TO 99}` Ej: R12-54-03

`Y-{A TO Z}` Ej: Y-Z

you can help me with this problem? I am a denied with regular expressions

all code should be in uppercase.

This question is problematic?

i use this code to parse the string:

```
$parts = explode("-",strtotupper($row['ubicacion']));
                    if(!empty($parts)){
                        if(is_array($parts)){
                            if(count($parts)==3){
                                if((strlen($parts[0]==2) || strlen($parts[0]==3)) && strlen($parts[1]==2) && strlen($parts[2]==2){
                                    $num = str_replace("R","",$parts[0]);
                                    if(is_numeric($num) && is_numeric($parts[1]) && is_numeric($parts[2])){
                                        if($num>=1 && $num <=12){
                                            $parse = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This link may help: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: Use the code from my answer and replace the `$string` argument in the function call (last line) with `$row['ubicacion']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First pattern

What you want to achieve is match some strings containing **ranges of numbers**. Regular expressions would do the job for **ranges of digits**, e.g.

```
[0-9]
```

will match *any digit from 0 to 9*. It's hard to use RegExp to match *one or more digits*  ranges, like 1-17.

I'd suggest developing an algorithm which will slice the string into specific parts and check each part to determine if the whole string matches.
Here's an example:

```
function stringMatches($string) {

    // is the first character NOT the 'R' letter
    if (0 !== strpos($string, 'R')) {
        return false;
    }

    $parts = explode('-', substr($string, 1));

    // is there more (or less) dash-separated numbers than 3
    if (count($parts) !== 3) {
        return false;
    }

    // is the first number NOT from 1-12 range
    if ($parts[0] > 12 || $parts[0] < 1) {
        return false;
    }

    // is the second number NOT from range 0-99 except the '00' case
    if ($parts[1] !== '00' && ($parts[1] > 99 || $parts[1] < 1)) {
        return false;
    }

    // is the third number NOT from range 0-99 except the '00' case
    if ($parts[2] !== '00' && ($parts[2] > 99 || $parts[2] < 1)) {
        return false;
    }

    // the string is ok
    return true;
}

$string = 'R12-54-03';
stringMatches($string); //will return TRUE if the string is OK
```

As you can see, the function is pretty big but I can assure you, it is much faster than simplest RegExp.

### Second pattern

When it comes to the second pattern - `Y-{A-Z}`, here the RegExp will be the easier and faster approach:

```
preg_match('/Y-[A-Z]/', $string);
```

Comment: @50l3r wrap your code with apostrophes (on the keyboard, below the tilde) because I can't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/R([1-9]|1[012])-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/', 'R12-54-03', $mats);

preg_match_all('/Y-([A-Z])/', 'Y-Z', $mats);
```